# Virtual, temporary phone

Tags: webapp-rec

I've just found that to sign up for Gmail account, I need to give Google my mobile phone number to verify me (they send me SMS message with short code etc.).

So, I'm thinking now, is there such web app (free; I have found for a few, but I need to pay to use them) that is a virtual phone number?

It may be temporary, like [10 minute mail](http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html).

Comment: It don't answer your question, but I think the SMS part is optionnal, as i can't remember having to give one (as I don't even live in US nor have a cell phone to receive the SMS).

Comment: Same as http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/how-can-i-get-around-giving-my-mobile-phone-number-to-google ?

Comment: @Alexandre Rafalovitch: GMail verification system was my first motivation, but now I am interested in such app, that can be used as a virtual-temporary phone number.

Comment: voxox.com k7.net ipkall.com sipgate.com all may do this, but you may have to use voice verification, not SMS verification with some of these.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good idea at first glance, but the first problem I can see is that phone numbers are far more finite than email addresses, so you will quickly run out of unique numbers.

There could be a way to do this with extensions perhaps, so the number could be +12125551234p99994858 where 99994858 is your unique number, but then most apps will verify a phone number to a specific mask that will likely reject this as a valid number.

It would be interesting to explore this idea further though...

Comment: There is a couple of free forward and phone mask services. The problem is how to monetize them long term. What I have seen is the phone numbers used as a sort of bit.ly forward with analytics. Voice is much more expensive than emails, so it is a bit hard to figure out how to make money around 'free' temporary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [inumbr](http://www.inumbr.com/) used to offer this kind of service (see this [Lifehacker](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=disposable%20free%20phone%20number&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-free-temporary-phone-numbers-easily-with-inumbr/&ei=c9z4ToT3I4KJ4gSxn8iNCA&usg=AFQjCNFx4CGoiJMOhVVVpDxOmUvw4HuJLw&sig2=Ss4Cw6HulxtsrP9nh2TdGw) article), but this is no longer the case. Now they charge for all their services.

There is a fairly simple alternative: Why don't you buy a prepaid mobile number and use it with an old mobile phone? Receiving SMS poses no problem. Over here in Europe they cost between nothing and 20 $. They can be used for some time. If you do not recharge them, they will expire. Of course, you may have to provide some kind of ID to get a card, but it keeps your real number safe.