# New Gmail account requires mobile number only on select devices

Tags: gmail, google-account, registration

On creating a new Gmail account, they first asked for all the details. I didn't add my mobile number as I did not want to give it away and left Current Email as blank.  After agreeing its TAC, the next page asked for a mobile number. It was [This](https://accounts.google.com/UserSignUpIdvChallenge) page. They have this on their [support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/114129?hl=en&ref_topic=3382296) page :

> Why Google asks for your phone number to verify your account?
>
> In an effort to protect our users from abuse, we sometimes ask users to prove they’re not a robot before they're able to create or sign in to accounts. Having this additional confirmation via phone is an effective way to keep spammers from abusing our systems.

Note ***sometimes***, but I get this same step every time I create an account. Earlier this didn't happen on my iPad tablet. Doing the same on my PC doesn't get to that page asking for the number.

So what criteria makes them ask for number in some devices and not in others?

How to bypass this?

<sub>I have read [How can I get around giving my mobile phone number to Google?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/how-can-i-get-around-giving-my-mobile-phone-number-to-google) but my concern is based on **devices used**. This pops up only on my iPad tablet and not on my PC.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get around giving my mobile phone number to Google?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/how-can-i-get-around-giving-my-mobile-phone-number-to-google)

Comment: @AlE. I have read that . My concern is based on devices . It happens only on my tablet but not on my pc .

Comment: Are you using the web app through the browser or an app?

Comment: Both the browser and the app from the tablet gives this while the pc skips it easily .

Comment: Hopefully if you select remember this device it wont be asking for verification.

Comment: @Vembu How do I do that _while creating the account_ ?

Comment: While first time entering the verification here check this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838?hl=en

Comment: @Vembu  Where exactly on this page https://accounts.google.com/SignUp   ??

Comment: Which operating system does the tablet run? Is it Android or something else?

Comment: @tepples iOS . The problem got resolved , look at my answer . If you have knowledge on the OS part of the answer , please improvise the post . Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am saying the following on my experience :

Google uses this feature to prevent spammers from creating hordes of email .

Many criterias are used for detecting patterns and to localize a possible abuser.
 (usually spammers arise from same areas ) (No ! I aint one !)

They use **IP addresses , MAC addresses , OS Systems** (not that very sure) , **Browsers**    (including version) (and clearing browsing data might help too) , **geographic locations , time intervals**(frequency of creation) and **devices used** to target this page (the one asking for mobile verification) on that particular user.

Changing *any one* of them will make one lose oneself in the crowd .

The ***sometimes*** that I referred is probably due to usage of **same device** and the **time interval** factor.